# Sorting plist data

Tags: swift, dictionary, property-list

I've got some repeating data in a plist, I then extract it into a dictionary and display it in my app. The only problem is that it needs to be in the same order i put it in the plist, but obviously, dictionary's can't be sorted and it comes out unsorted. So how would i achieve this?

My plist data repeats like this

[image]

I then convert that into a dictionary of type `[Int : ItemType]`, ItemType is my data protocol, like this:

```
class ExhibitionUnarchiver {
    class func exhibitionsFromDictionary(_ dictionary: [String: AnyObject]) throws -> [Int : ItemType] {
        var inventory: [Int : ItemType] = [:]
        var i = 0;

        print(dictionary)

        for (key, value) in dictionary {
            if let itemDict = value as? [String : String],
            let title = itemDict["title"],
            let audio = itemDict["audio"],
            let image = itemDict["image"],
            let description = itemDict["description"]{
                let item = ExhibitionItem(title: title, image: image, audio: audio, description: description)
                inventory.updateValue(item, forKey: i);
                i += 1;
            }
        }

        return inventory
    }
}
```

Which results in a dictionary like this:

```
[12: App.ExhibitionItem(title: "Water Bonsai", image: "waterbonsai.jpg", audio: "exhibit-audio-1", description: "blah blah blah"), 17: App.ExhibitionItem.....
```

I was hoping that since i made the key's Int's i could sort it but so far i'm having no luck. You might be able to tell i'm fairly new to swift, so please provide any info you think would be relevant. Thanks!

Comment: I think the only way to maintain the order would be to use an array instead of a dictionary. If the `Int` key in the dictionary is important, I would store it as a sibling next to "title", etc.

Comment: It's easy to convert an array into a dictionary in code, but it's impossible to maintain order in a dictionary.

Comment: I have been thinking about that... but becuase it's part of the `ExhibitionItem` struct, i can't just sort it like a normal array can i?

Comment: I'm confused by your comment. I assume you want the `ExhibitionItem`s to be sorted right? If you use an array instead of the dictionary with numeric keys, your order will be preserved. Arrays are inherently ordered, dictionaries are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Dictionary has no order. If you need a specific order, make `root` of type `Array`:

[image]

---

or sort it by the key manually:

```
var root = [Int:[String:String]]()
root[1] = ["title":"Hi"]
root[2] = ["title":"Ho"]

let result = root.sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }

print(result)
```

prints:

```
[(1, ["title": "Hi"]), (2, ["title": "Ho"])]
```

Comment: If the root was an array how would i sort by the key, in your example "Item 0", "Item 1" etc

Comment: @ShanRobertson An array is ordered from index 0 to the index at count - 1. It's *already* in the order you want it in.

Comment: Exactly. The enumeration key would be obsolete. Added sorting example to the answer  also.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification... seems rather silly of me to have missed this but like i said, i am new! I changed the plist to an array of dictionaries and it all came out the right way.

Comment: @ShanRobertson no worries.